# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppStateNotifier> above this Consumer<AppStateNotifier> Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-build

the following error occurs after I tried adding the provider feature to my app:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget

This is my code for the ChangeNotifier:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppStateNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDarkMode = false;

  void updateTheme(bool isDarkMode) {
    this.isDarkMode = isDarkMode;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And there is my main class:

```dart
import 'package:wilson/src/config/theme_data.dart';
import 'package:wilson/src/routes/index.dart';
import 'package:wilson/src/utils/app_state_notifier.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Wilson extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wilson({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppStateNotifier>(builder: (context, appState, child) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App-Name',
        theme: ThemeConfig.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: ThemeConfig.darkTheme,
        themeMode: appState.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
        onGenerateRoute: routes,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me with that, because I believe it's just a stupid little mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize this into your main.dart like this.
You can use multi provider if you have more than one provider files.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Doctorss()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Categoriess()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: TopDoctors()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Appointments()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: TopArticlesProvider()),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.blue[800]),
        primaryColor: Colors.blue[800],
        colorScheme:
            ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.orange)),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapShot) {
          if (snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Start();
          }
          if (snapShot.hasData) {
            return const homestate();
          }
          return const AuthScreen();
        }),
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by initializing?

Comment: You have to add provider class file to main.dart like the code is shown above