# Error: could not find the correct Provider<List<Parking>> above this ParkingList Widget

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_user_profile/home/parking_tile.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'parking_tile.dart';
import '../model/parking.dart';

class ParkingList extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  State<ParkingList> createState() => _ParkingListState();
}

class _ParkingListState extends State<ParkingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final parkings = Provider.of<List<Parking>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: parkings.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return ParkingTile(parking: parkings[index]);
    },
    );
    return Container();
  }
}
```

And heres my coding for main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter_user_profile/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_user_profile/model/user.dart';

Future <void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(apiKey: "AIzaSyD59Nz0y4Z8S-rVpeu5E5lslsW_8WYrEiE",
          appId: "XXX", messagingSenderId: "XXX", projectId: "parkingtech-f1449") );
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return StreamProvider<Client?>.value(
        initialData: null,
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Wrapper(),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

when I run the app it could not find the correct provider and I'm not sure how to solve this,I've tried most of the solution but it seems that I still cant find the right way to do it. I'm still new to flutter please help

Comment: Have you registered this `Parking` in your main.dart?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered this Parking in your main.dart ?
If didn't, look at the mine answer.. Thanks

[Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppStateNotifier> above this Consumer<AppStateNotifier> Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843164/error-could-not-find-the-correct-providerappstatenotifier-above-this-consumer/71843678#71843678)

Comment: I already put the main.dart file at the above, I'm not sure how to return two things or put the changenotifier as I already return a streamprovider

Comment: Can you please show parking class code ?

Comment: You need to wrap Material App with provider.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap you main app (parent class) with a provider (depending on the use case)!

Please check out the official documentation of Provider package to understand how to add a provider in the main app.

Link to the original package on pub: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Example: https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example

Comment: Please add code samples within your answers, as opposed to sharing a link. Links break!